# C - return array of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, c99

Suppose I want to write (in C99) the following function:

```
NAME: primes
INPUT: an integer n > 0
OUTPUT: int array filled with the prime numbers in range [2, n]
```

How can I return such an array from my function? Is that possible?

---

Note that I **don't** want the caller to allocate an `n * sizeof(int)` array that I'll fill with 0 (composite) and 1 (primes).

I can't just return a pointer to the array, because the caller has no way to know how long the array is:

```
int * primes(int n)
{
    int * arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    // do stuff
    return arr;
} 

int main(void)
{
    int * arr = primes(100);
    printf("%lu \n", sizeof arr); // prints 8
}
```

and I can't change the signature like this:

```
int (*primes(int n))[LENGTH]
```

because LENGTH is unknown at compile time.

---

I read somewhere something like "to return a struct with the array is an horrible idea", and, well... that was my last idea.

**What's the best practice in cases like this?**

Comment: You can return an allocated pointer as you show, that's not an issue. However, `sizeof(arr)` will be the size of the pointer, not the length of the array. So you'll get 8 you're on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @mbratch that's the problem. What if the caller want to iterate over the primes?

`for(int i = 0; i < ??????; i++)`

Comment: Show some code how you want the iteration to work. You need to define `??????` somehow. How does the user decide that number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the function that you call must decide the actual number of elements that it needs to allocate, you should pass a pointer to the allocated length along with the rest of the parameters, like this:

```
size_t actual_length;
int *arr = primes(100, &actual_length);
if (arr == NULL) {
    ... // Report an error
}
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != actual_length ; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

The `primes` would then look like this:

```
int *primes(int count, size_t *actual_length) {
    size_t primes_needed = ...
    int *res = malloc(sizeof(*res)*primes_needed);
    *actual_length = primes_needed;
    // Do calculations, perhaps some reallocs
    // Don't forget to reassign *actual_length = ... on realloc
    ...
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This is **exactly** the kind of idiom I was looking for.

Comment: +1 almost perfect, but maybe change `sizeof(int)` to `sizeof *res` :)

Comment: @H2CO3 That's a nice change, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're welcome. Everybody needs to have his code reviewed ;-)

Answer (score 4):

When an array is allocated with `malloc` you can't request its size with `sizeof`. Common practice in these situations is to return the size of the array and assign it to a pointer-pointer given as an argument. Like this:

```
int primes(int n, int ** arr){
    int length = n;
    *arr = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    // do stuff...
    // if *arr is realloc()ed update length
    return length;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
int * arr;
length = primes(100, &arr);
```

An example of a standard function that does this is [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread). It takes as an argument an array and the number of elements (and size of the elements) it should read. It then returns the number of elements it actually read, which may be less, if for example the end of the file was reached.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your example (or I can't understand it). You return `n`, but `n` is not the size of the primes array. The array contains just the primes in the range [2, n], the its length is less than n.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was going with your original `primes` function that uses `n` for the initial `malloc`. You could change `n` in the function if the size of the array changes.

Comment: "If the size of an array isn't known at compile time you can't request it with sizeof" - wrong, we have VLAs since 1999. "sizeof is more similar to a macro than a function" - wrong, it's not a macro either, it's an **operator.**

Comment: @H2CO3 fair enough, though I never said `sizeof` *is* a macro, just that it's definitely not a function (though its syntax can look like it).

Comment: @Kninnug Yes, it's kind of confusing because *sometimes* it requires parenthesizing (when its argument is a type name, to be precise). One more correction: `fread()` does return the length, but it doesn't allocate memory for the buffer it fills. (But +1 anyway for having shown the other option.)

Comment: @Kninnug +1. Your solution took me longer to understand, but I like it. I'm accepting dasblinkenlight answer because I slightly prefer a version that returns the array and sets the length (opposite of what you do). Thanks!